# How to pass Retrofit API call as a parameter?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I want to pass a Retrofit API Call as a parameter to a method. Here is my minified code:

```
interface API {
    @POST("/test")
    fun postTest(): Call<Response>
}
```

```
fun test() {
   post(client.postTest())
}
```

```
private lateinit var client: Api


private fun post(function: Call<Response>) {
 if (::client.isInitialized) {
   function.enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Response>,
                    response: Response<Response>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        // do something
                    } else {
                        // do something
                    }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
                    // do something
            }
         })
   }
}
```

The APIClient is initiated correctly. My problem is that the API Call is executed before passed to the post()-function, which leads to unhandled errors if something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a method reference that will create your `Call` object lazily in your `post` function:

```
fun test() {
   post(client::postTest)
}

private fun post(lazyCall: () -> Call<Response>) {
   lazyCall().enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
     //...
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i guess i need to specify my problem a little bit more:
i check if the client is initialized at the start of my post function (see my updated code snippet) - with your solution, i am still getting an error when calling it. I dont want to check if its initialized in every test() function

Comment: @dav1d337 if your client can be null before you call `post` that's a misuse of lateinit var, it should either be nullable or you should use a lazy delegate to initialize it.